# MS Excel For Each Loop: Insert Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet containing 242 rows. I want to create a new row beneath each existing one. Instead, my code creates 242 rows below row 1. I have spent all afternoon on Google and Stack Overflow and tried various ideas but get the same problem. Here's my code:

```
Function rws() As Integer

rws = (Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row)

End Function

Sub InsRws()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & rws - 1)

For Each row In rng.Rows
    Rows.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Please select one of the posts that best suits your question as a answer

Comment: Yes, if one of the proposed answers solved your problem then you should "Accept" it for the benefit of future readers (and to give some reputation points to the person who took the time to help you).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help

```
Function rws() As Integer

rws = (Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row)

End Function

Sub InsRws()
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    rowCount = rws
    For i = 1 To rowCount
         Range("A" + CStr(2 * i - 1)).Select
         ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to count up rather down down, like this

```
Sub InsertRows()
    Dim rw As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            .Rows(rw).Insert
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you debug in for each loop **`debug.print row.address`** you will notice your rng keeps expanding when there is an insert. Instead you can use for loop as in below code.

```
Sub InsRws()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Range("A" & i * 2).EntireRow.Insert
    Next

End Sub
```