# getting "application-defined or object defined" error

Tags: excel, vba

i wrote the below code to check two cells in a row if both have 0 in them then it should hide that row

```
For Each rr In Range("I17:I28")  'rr is defined as range
        If rr = 0 Then

            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range(rr).Value = 0 Then  ' getting error in this line
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("B16").Select

            Else
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("B16").Select
            End If

        End If
Next
```

but i am getting "application-defined or object defined" error
i tried replacing range(rr) to simply rr but still it is giving "Object dosen't support this property or method" error

please help on this....

Comment: You're referencing two different range objects in the problem line, ActiveCell and rr. Use one or the other `ActiveCell.Offset(..).Value or rr.Offset(0,-3).Value (not sure which you are intending).

Comment: @chuff i tried rr.offset(0,-3) but it is hiding column 18 but it hase to hide column 17 (cus it is having 0 in I and F not row 18)

Comment: @murugan_kotheesan [This link may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001937/ms-excel-for-each-loop-insert-rows/16002805#16002805)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the below code whether it works fine for you... It hides first row if there are two consecutive 0's. if there are three consecutive zeros it hide first two and so on...

```
Sub CheckZeros()
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I17:I28")
 For i = 1 To rng.Count
   If rng.Cells(i, 1) = rng.Cells(i + 1, 1) And rng.Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then
     rng.Cells(i, "I").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this is hiding only the first row which satisfies the conditing not the rest in that range

Comment: If you want to hide all consecutive 0's. please add the another line "rng.Cells(i + 1, "I").EntireRow.Hidden = True"